# Element API unable to get all() of matrix field

Tags: matrix, plugin-elementapi

I'm getting matrix block content from an entry type which works fine for the most part. It's probably clearer to just paste in the code:

Current element api code:

```
$relationsData = [];    
if($entry->relatedContent){
    $index = -1;
    foreach ($entry->relatedContent->all() as $block) {
        switch ($block->type->handle) {
            case 'relateContent':
                $index++;
                $relatedFeaturedEntries =  $block->featured->first();
                $relatedSubEntries =  $block->related->first();
                $relationsData[$index] = [
                    'title' => $relatedFeaturedEntries->title,
                    'url' => $relatedFeaturedEntries->url
                ];
                $relationsData[$index]['subItems'] = [];
                $relationsData[$index]['subItems'][] = [
                    'title' => $relatedSubEntries->title,
                    'url' => $relatedSubEntries->url
                ];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
      "relations": [
        {
          "title": "Testing workflow",
          "url": "http://localhost/blah",
          "subItems": [
            {
              "title": "Help & Guidance",
              "url": "http://localhost/help-guidance"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "title": "Taking part in the blah",
          "url": "http://localhost/blah",
          "subItems": [
            {
              "title": "blah timeline",
              "url": "http://localhost/blah"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "title": "Testing workflow",
          "url": "http://localhost/blah",
          "subItems": [
            {
              "title": "Completing on paper",
              "url": "http://localhost/blah"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
```

There should be more `subItems` in each `subItems` array but I am only getting the first because I'm fetching them using `$relatedSubEntries =  $block->related->first();` But nothing else works and just errors i.e. `all()` or removing `first()`

Comment: "But nothing else works and just errors" - what are the errors?

Comment: `Trying to get property of non-object`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out in the end. As an array is being returned I just needed a for loop to get inside it.

Solution...

```
                    if($entry->relatedContent){
                        $index = -1;
                        foreach ($entry->relatedContent->all() as $block) {
                            switch ($block->type->handle) {
                                case 'relateContent':
                                    $index++;
                                    $relatedFeaturedEntries =  $block->featured->first();
                                    $relationsData[$index] = [
                                        'title' => $relatedFeaturedEntries->title,
                                        'url' => $relatedFeaturedEntries->url
                                    ];

                                    $relationsData[$index]['subItems'] = [];
                                    $relatedSubEntries =  $block->related->all();
                                    foreach ($relatedSubEntries as $relatedSubEntry) {
                                        $relationsData[$index]['subItems'][] = [
                                            'title' => $relatedSubEntry->title,
                                            'url' => $relatedSubEntry->url
                                        ];
                                    }
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
```